# Format XML Response for HTML Dropdown in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml, xslt

I have javascript onChange function that calls a PHP file to run through, get UPS rates, and return an HTML update with a rate dropdown list.  I had this all working just fine, but now I need to add an item to the options list based on a comparison.

Javascript:

```js
function fetch_UPS(el){
    var zip = el;
    if (zip.length !== 5) {
        alert ("Please enter a valid 5-digit US zip code.");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var cartID = getCookie('cornerstoreid');
        document.getElementById('blackoverlay').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('pp_checkout').style.display = "none";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            url: 'fetch_rates.php',
            data: { zip : zip, cartID : cartID },
            success: function(response){
                var droplist = document.getElementById("shipping_field");
                var htmlchange = "<span class=\"cart_opt_label\">Shipping: </span>" + response;
                droplist.innerHTML = htmlchange;
                document.getElementById('blackoverlay').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('btn_sub_txt').innerHTML = '<input type="button" id="pp_checkout" value="" onclick="paypal_checkout_submit();" style="display:none;" />Please update shipping to continue';
            }
        });
    }
}
```

PHP for return (cut out all of the bits before the return)

```php
if ($response == false) {
        throw new Exception ( "Bad data." );
    } else {
        // save request and response to file
        $fw = fopen ( $outputFileName, 'w' );
        fwrite ( $fw, $response );
        fclose ( $fw );
        
        // Load XML file
        $xml = new DOMDocument;
        $xml->load($outputFileName);

        // Load XSL file
        $xsl = new DOMDocument;
        $xsl->load('style.xsl');

        // Configure the transformer
        $proc = new XSLTProcessor;

        // Attach the xsl rules
        $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

        echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
    }
```

XSL stylesheet:

```xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <select name="shipping_options" id="shipping_options">
        <xsl:for-each select="/RatingServiceSelectionResponse/RatedShipment">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Service/Code = 01">
                <xsl:element name="option"><xsl:attribute name='value'>1!!!<xsl:value-of select="TotalCharges/MonetaryValue + 4"/></xsl:attribute>UPS Next Day Air - $<xsl:value-of select="format-number(TotalCharges/MonetaryValue + 4, '###,###.00')"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="Service/Code = 02">
                <xsl:element name="option">
                    <xsl:attribute name='value'>2!!!<xsl:value-of select="TotalCharges/MonetaryValue + 4"/></xsl:attribute>UPS 2nd Day Air - $<xsl:value-of select="format-number(TotalCharges/MonetaryValue + 4, '###,###.00')"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>         
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name="option">No Data</xsl:element>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <option value='8!!!0.00'>Please call for freight pricing</option>
        <option value='9!!!0.00'>Please call for international pricing</option>
    </select>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried removing the final 2 options and the closing `select` tag from the XSL stylesheet and adding right after the `echo`

```php
$closeTag = '<option value=\'8!!!0.00\'>Please call for freight pricing</option>
    <option value=\'9!!!0.00\'>Please call for international pricing</option>
    </select>';
if ($to_height > 0 && $to_height <= 2) {
        echo $closeTag;
    }
    else {
        echo $closeTag;
    }
```

On testing, my `IF` statements work to just add a string to the end of the return, but if I try to remove the closing `select` tag from the XSL and add it to the PHP file instead, it drops the formatted return and only returns anything after the `IF` statement.

I don't do a lot of coding, and since there's usually 6 months to a year in between, I'm frequently behind on the current coding requirements.  I'm sure there's just some XSL rule that I'm missing, but I have tried every search combination I could think of and haven't come up with any solutions.

Comment: Questions that are the result of a typo or similar mistake are off-topic, as they provide little value for future visitors. Instead of posting an answer, you can simply delete the question.

Comment: I disagree.  while yes, my problem was solved by fixing a coding error, after a couple hours of searching, I was not able to find ANY examples of using this combination to format the XML return into the middle of a select block for a HTML formatted return like this.  Which, if I had been able to find one, I probably would have noticed my error right away.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out.

When I originally removed the last two options and the closing tag, I left in the opening `SELECT` tag in the XSL stylesheet.  This was causing the stylesheet to fail because it had an opening tag with no closing tag.  Once I removed the `SELECT` tag line from the XSL stylesheet and made the following changes to the PHP, everything worked perfect.

This is the changes to the PHP:

```php
$openTag = '<select name="shipping_options" id="shipping_options">';
$closeTag = '<option value=\'8!!!0.00\'>Please call for freight pricing</option>
        <option value=\'9!!!0.00\'>Please call for international pricing</option>
    </select>';

....

else {
        // save request and response to file
        $fw = fopen ( $outputFileName, 'w' );
        fwrite ( $fw, $response );
        fclose ( $fw );
        
        // Load XML file
        $xml = new DOMDocument;
        $xml->load($outputFileName);

        // Load XSL file
        $xsl = new DOMDocument;
        $xsl->load('style.xsl');

        // Configure the transformer
        $proc = new XSLTProcessor;

        // Attach the xsl rules
        $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

        echo $openTag;
        echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
        if ($to_height > 0 && $to_height <= 2) {
            echo $openTag . 'extra text here' . $closeTag;
        }
        else {
            echo $openTag . $closeTag;
        }
    }
```